# Did not get solution after searching a lot - Only GET is working - POST, DELETE, PUT all are giving 405, Request method <> not supported

Tags: angular, spring-boot

I'm trying to create an application in Spring boot and angular JS which we have admin USER account creation and admin would be able to add multiple stores from which end user would be able to find the nearest shop by hitting their address

The issue is, Admin console is working as expected but now Admin user is not able to submit POST call to add store address

Must be making mistake somewhere in mapping only - any help/pointer would really help

FIrst controller **SuperAdminAppController**

```
 @Controller
 @RequestMapping("/")
 @SessionAttributes("roles")
 public class SuperAdminAppController {

 @Autowired
 SuperAdminUserService superAdminUserService;

@Autowired
SuperAdminUserProfileService userProfileService;

@Autowired
MessageSource messageSource;

@Autowired
PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices 
persistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices;

@Autowired
AuthenticationTrustResolver authenticationTrustResolver;


/**
 * This method will list all existing users.
 */
@RequestMapping(value = { "/", "/list" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String listUsers(ModelMap model) {

    List<SuperAdminUser> users = superAdminUserService.findAllUsers();
    model.addAttribute("users", users);
    model.addAttribute("loggedinuser", getPrincipal());
    return "userslist";
}

/**
 * This method will provide the medium to add a new user.
 */
@RequestMapping(value = { "/newuser" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String newUser(ModelMap model) {
    SuperAdminUser user = new SuperAdminUser();
    model.addAttribute("user", user);
    model.addAttribute("edit", false);
    model.addAttribute("loggedinuser", getPrincipal());
    return "registration";
}

/**
 * This method will be called on form submission, handling POST request for
 * saving user in database. It also validates the user input
 */
@RequestMapping(value = { "/newuser" }, method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String saveUser(@Valid SuperAdminUser user, BindingResult result,
        ModelMap model) {

    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        return "registration";
    }

    /*
     * Preferred way to achieve uniqueness of field [sso] should be implementing custom @Unique annotation
     * and applying it on field [sso] of Model class [User].
     *
     * Below mentioned peace of code [if block] is to demonstrate that you can fill custom errors outside the validation
     * framework as well while still using internationalized messages.
     *
     */
    if(!superAdminUserService.isUserSSOUnique(user.getId(), user.getSsoId())){
        FieldError ssoError =new FieldError("user","ssoId",messageSource.getMessage("non.unique.ssoId", new String[]{user.getSsoId()}, Locale.getDefault()));
        result.addError(ssoError);
        return "registration";
    }

    superAdminUserService.saveUser(user);

    model.addAttribute("success", "User " + user.getFirstName() + " "+ user.getLastName() + " registered successfully");
    model.addAttribute("loggedinuser", getPrincipal());
    //return "success";
    return "registrationsuccess";
}


/**
 * This method will provide the medium to update an existing user.
 */
@RequestMapping(value = { "/edit-user-{ssoId}" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String editUser(@PathVariable String ssoId, ModelMap model) {
    SuperAdminUser user = superAdminUserService.findBySSO(ssoId);
    model.addAttribute("user", user);
    model.addAttribute("edit", true);
    model.addAttribute("loggedinuser", getPrincipal());
    return "registration";
}

/**
 * This method will be called on form submission, handling POST request for
 * updating user in database. It also validates the user input
 */
@RequestMapping(value = { "/edit-user-{ssoId}" }, method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String updateUser(@Valid SuperAdminUser user, BindingResult result,
        ModelMap model, @PathVariable String ssoId) {

    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        return "registration";
    }

    /*//Uncomment below 'if block' if you WANT TO ALLOW UPDATING SSO_ID in UI which is a unique key to a User.
    if(!userService.isUserSSOUnique(user.getId(), user.getSsoId())){
        FieldError ssoError =new FieldError("user","ssoId",messageSource.getMessage("non.unique.ssoId", new String[]{user.getSsoId()}, Locale.getDefault()));
        result.addError(ssoError);
        return "registration";
    }*/


    superAdminUserService.updateUser(user);

    model.addAttribute("success", "User " + user.getFirstName() + " "+ user.getLastName() + " updated successfully");
    model.addAttribute("loggedinuser", getPrincipal());
    return "registrationsuccess";
}


/**
 * This method will delete an user by it's SSOID value.
 */
@RequestMapping(value = { "/delete-user-{ssoId}" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String deleteUser(@PathVariable String ssoId) {
    superAdminUserService.deleteUserBySSO(ssoId);
    return "redirect:/list";
}


/**
 * This method will provide UserProfile list to views
 */
@ModelAttribute("roles")
public List<SuperAdminUserProfile> initializeProfiles() {
    return userProfileService.findAll();
}

/**
 * This method handles Access-Denied redirect.
 */
@RequestMapping(value = "/Access_Denied", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String accessDeniedPage(ModelMap model) {
    model.addAttribute("loggedinuser", getPrincipal());
    return "accessDenied";
}

/**
 * This method handles login GET requests.
 * If users is already logged-in and tries to goto login page again, will be redirected to list page.
 */
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String loginPage() {
    if (isCurrentAuthenticationAnonymous()) {
        return "login";
    } else {
        return "redirect:/list";
    }
}

/**
 * This method handles logout requests.
 * Toggle the handlers if you are RememberMe functionality is useless in your app.
 */
@RequestMapping(value="/logout", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String logoutPage (HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){
    Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    if (auth != null){
        //new SecurityContextLogoutHandler().logout(request, response, auth);
        persistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices.logout(request, response, auth);
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(null);
    }
    return "redirect:/login?logout";
}

/**
 * This method returns the principal[user-name] of logged-in user.
 */
private String getPrincipal(){
    String userName = null;
    Object principal = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();

    if (principal instanceof UserDetails) {
        userName = ((UserDetails)principal).getUsername();
    } else {
        userName = principal.toString();
    }
    return userName;
}

/**
 * This method returns true if users is already authenticated [logged-in], else false.
 */
private boolean isCurrentAuthenticationAnonymous() {
    final Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    return authenticationTrustResolver.isAnonymous(authentication);
}


}
```

Second controller - **RestApiController**

```
 @RestController
 @RequestMapping("/api")
 public class RestApiController {

 public static final Logger logger = 
 LoggerFactory.getLogger(RestApiController.class);

@Autowired
UserService userService; // Service which will do all data
// retrieval/manipulation work

// -------------------Retrieve All
// Users---------------------------------------------

@RequestMapping(value = "/user/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<List<User>> listAllUsers() {
    List<User> users = userService.findAllUsers();
    if (users.isEmpty()) {
        return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
        // You many decide to return HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<List<User>>(users, HttpStatus.OK);
 }

// -------------------Retrieve Single
// User------------------------------------------

@RequestMapping(value = "/user/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<?> getUser(@PathVariable("id") long id) {
    logger.info("Fetching User with id {}", id);
    User user = userService.findById(id);
    if (user == null) {
        logger.error("User with id {} not found.", id);
        return new ResponseEntity(new CustomErrorType("User with id " + id + 
   " not found"), HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<User>(user, HttpStatus.OK);
   }

  // -------------------Create a
  // User-------------------------------------------

  /*@RequestMapping(value = "/{pathURL}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
  public String post(@ModelAttribute("AppUser") AppUser appUser, ModelMap 
  modelMap,@PathVariable String pathURL)


  @RequestMapping(value = "/{pathURL}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public String get(ModelMap modelMap,@PathVariable String pathURL)*/

  @RequestMapping(value = "/user/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
  public ResponseEntity<?> createUser(@RequestBody User user, 
  UriComponentsBuilder ucBuilder) {

    logger.info("Creating User : {}", user);

    if (userService.isUserExist(user)) {
        logger.error("Unable to create. A User with name {} already exist", 
 user.getName());
        return new ResponseEntity(
                new CustomErrorType("Unable to create. A User with name " + 
  user.getName() + " already exist."),
                HttpStatus.CONFLICT);
    }
    userService.saveUser(user);

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();

     headers.setLocation(ucBuilder.path("/api/user/{id}").
     buildAndExpand(user.getId()).toUri());
    return new ResponseEntity<String>(headers, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }


// ------------------- Update a User
// ------------------------------------------------

@RequestMapping(value = "/user/{id}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
public ResponseEntity<?> updateUser(@PathVariable("id") long id, @RequestBody User user) {
    logger.info("Updating User with id {}", id);

    User currentUser = userService.findById(id);

    if (currentUser == null) {
        logger.error("Unable to update. User with id {} not found.", id);
        return new ResponseEntity(new CustomErrorType("Unable to upate. User with id " + id + " not found."),
                HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }

    currentUser.setName(user.getName());
    currentUser.setPnumber(user.getPnumber());
    currentUser.setAddress(user.getAddress());
    currentUser.setLat(getLat(user.getAddress().toString()));
    currentUser.setLon(getLon(user.getAddress().toString()));
    currentUser.setWork_price(user.getWork_price());
    currentUser.setLocation(user.getLocation());
    currentUser.setComment(user.getComment());
    currentUser.setPreference(user.getPreference());

    userService.updateUser(currentUser);
    return new ResponseEntity<User>(currentUser, HttpStatus.OK);
}

// ------------------- Delete a
// User-----------------------------------------

@RequestMapping(value = "/user/{id}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
public ResponseEntity<?> deleteUser(@PathVariable("id") long id) {
    logger.info("Fetching & Deleting User with id {}", id);

    User user = userService.findById(id);
    if (user == null) {
        logger.error("Unable to delete. User with id {} not found.", id);
        return new ResponseEntity(new CustomErrorType("Unable to delete. User with id " + id + " not found."),
                HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }
    userService.deleteUserById(id);
    return new ResponseEntity<User>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
}

// ------------------- Delete All Users-----------------------------

@RequestMapping(value = "/user/", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
public ResponseEntity<User> deleteAllUsers() {
    logger.info("Deleting All Users");

    userService.deleteAllUsers();
    return new ResponseEntity<User>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
}


public String getLat(String add){
    Location loc = new Location();
    try {
        return loc.getLat(add);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    return null;
}

public String getLon(String add){
    Location loc = new Location();
    try {
        return loc.getLon(add);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    return null;
}

 }
```

My **log**

```
        2017-08-25 15:17:36.393  INFO 10268 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
        2017-08-25 15:17:37.941  INFO 10268 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/index]}" onto java.lang.String com.sezlon.maintenance.services.global.controller.AppController.home(org.springframework.ui.ModelMap)
        2017-08-25 15:17:37.943  INFO 10268 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/partials/{page}]}" onto java.lang.String com.sezlon.maintenance.services.global.controller.AppController.partialHandler(java.lang.String)
        2017-08-25 15:17:37.954  INFO 10268 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/api/user/{id}],methods=[DELETE]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<?> com.sezlon.maintenance.services.global.controller.RestApiController.deleteUser(long)
        2017-08-25 15:17:37.955  INFO 10268 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/api/user/],methods=[GET]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.List<com.sezlon.maintenance.services.global.model.User>> com.sezlon.maintenance.services.global.controller.RestApiController.listAllUsers()
        2017-08-25 15:17:37.955  INFO 10268 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/api/user/],methods=[DELETE]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<com.sezlon.maintenance.services.global.model.User> com.sezlon.maintenance.services.global.controller.RestApiController.deleteAllUsers()
        2017-08-25 15:17:37.955  INFO 10268 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/api/user/{id}],methods=[GET]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<?> com.sezlon.maintenance.services.global.controller.RestApiController.getUser(long)
        2017-08-25 15:17:37.955  INFO 10268 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/api/user/],methods=[POST]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<?> com.sezlon.maintenance.services.global.controller.RestApiController.createUser(com.sezlon.maintenance.services.global.model.User,org.springframework.web.util.UriComponentsBuilder)
        2017-08-25 15:17:37.955  INFO 10268 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/api/user/{id}],methods=[PUT]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<?> com.sezlon.maintenance.services.global.controller.RestApiController.updateUser(long,com.sezlon.maintenance.services.global.model.User)
        2017-08-25 15:17:37.961  INFO 10268 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/delete-user-{ssoId}],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.lang.String com.sezlon.maintenance.services.global.controller.SuperAdminAppController.deleteUser(java.lang.String)
        2017-08-25 15:17:37.961  INFO 10268 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/newuser],methods=[POST]}" onto public java.lang.String com.sezlon.maintenance.services.global.controller.SuperAdminAppController.saveUser(com.sezlon.maintenance.services.global.admin.model.SuperAdminUser,org.springframework.validation.BindingResult,org.springframework.ui.ModelMap)
        2017-08-25 15:17:37.962  INFO 10268 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/edit-user-{ssoId}],methods=[POST]}" onto public java.lang.String com.sezlon.maintenance.services.global.controller.SuperAdminAppController.updateUser(com.sezlon.maintenance.services.global.admin.model.SuperAdminUser,org.springframework.validation.BindingResult,org.springframework.ui.ModelMap,java.lang.String)
        2017-08-25 15:17:37.962  INFO 10268 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/edit-user-{ssoId}],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.lang.String com.sezlon.maintenance.services.global.controller.SuperAdminAppController.editUser(java.lang.String,org.springframework.ui.ModelMap)
        2017-08-25 15:17:37.962  INFO 10268 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/newuser],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.lang.String com.sezlon.maintenance.services.global.controller.SuperAdminAppController.newUser(org.springframework.ui.ModelMap)
        2017-08-25 15:17:37.962  INFO 10268 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/Access_Denied],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.lang.String com.sezlon.maintenance.services.global.controller.SuperAdminAppController.accessDeniedPage(org.springframework.ui.ModelMap)
        2017-08-25 15:17:37.962  INFO 10268 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/ || /list],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.lang.String com.sezlon.maintenance.services.global.controller.SuperAdminAppController.listUsers(org.springframework.ui.ModelMap)
        2017-08-25 15:17:37.962  INFO 10268 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/login],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.lang.String com.sezlon.maintenance.services.global.controller.SuperAdminAppController.loginPage()
        2017-08-25 15:17:37.962  INFO 10268 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/logout],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.lang.String com.sezlon.maintenance.services.global.controller.SuperAdminAppController.logoutPage(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
        2017-08-25 15:17:37.967  INFO 10268 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
        2017-08-25 15:17:37.968  INFO 10268 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
        2017-08-25 15:17:38.019  INFO 10268 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/static/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
        2017-08-25 15:17:38.269  INFO 10268 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@244038d0: startup date [Fri Aug 25 15:17:22 PDT 2017]; root of context hierarchy
```

Comment: How are making the web service calls? What urls are you using?

Comment: From this page "localhost:3030/test/index", I'm trying to hit api - "localhost:3030/test/api/user/"

Comment: What are your spring security settings?